# Converting a range into a bit array

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitarray

I'm writing a time-critical piece of code in C# that requires me to convert two unsigned integers that define an inclusive range into a bit field.  Ex:

```
uint x1 = 3;
uint x2 = 9;
  //defines the range [3-9]
  //                              98  7654 3
  //must be converted to:  0000 0011  1111 1000
```

It may help to visualize the bits in reverse order

The maximum value for this range is a parameter given at run-time which we'll call `max_val`.  Therefore, the bit field variable ought to be defined as a `UInt32` array with size equal to `max_val/32`:

```
UInt32 MAX_DIV_32 = max_val / 32;
UInt32[] bitArray = new UInt32[MAX_DIV_32];
```

Given a range defined by the variables `x1` and `x2`, what is the fastest way to perform this conversion?

Comment: Do most cases have max_val >= 32? Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use an array. If yes, then I assume you want to be able to say I need 200 bits set to 1 with a padding of 100 bits set to 0 on the right.

Comment: If your max_val is not divisible by 32, your bitArray is going to be missing some bits.

Comment: Samuel - not sure what you're getting at.

Jim - Yep, I know and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: The mods are gone ... you will have to benchmark. I daubt a table lookup will gain significant any speed.

Comment: Looks beautiful.  And I just discovered that the code I offered with table lookups is erroneous anyway.  Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: My pleasure! It was fun ... 06:00 in the morning (Germany) and I am going to bed now. Have to be back at work in a few hours. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Calculate the range of array items that must be filled with all ones and do this by iterating over this range. Finally set the items at both borders.

```
Int32 startIndex = x1 >> 5;
Int32 endIndex = x2 >> 5;

bitArray[startIndex] = UInt32.MaxValue << (x1 & 31);

for (Int32 i = startIndex + 1; i <= endIndex; i++)
{
   bitArray[i] = UInt32.MaxValue;
}

bitArray[endIndex] &= UInt32.MaxValue >> (31 - (x2 & 31));
```

May be the code is not 100% correct, but the idea should work.

---

Just tested it and found three bugs. The calculation at start index required a mod 32 and at end index the 32 must be 31 and a logical and instead of a assignment to handle the case of start and end index being the same. Should be quite fast.

---

Just benchmarked it with equal distribution of x1 and x2 over the array.
Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0 GHz, MS VirtualPC with Server 2003 R2 on Windows XP host.

```
Array length [bits]           320         160         64
Performance [executions/s]    33 million  43 million  54 million
```

---

One more optimazation x % 32 == x & 31 but I am unable to meassure a performance gain. Because of only 10.000.000 iterations in my test the fluctuations are quite high. And I am running in VirtualPC making the situation even more unpredictable.

Comment: Setting the value at `startIndex` is wrong here. You don't want to shift left by x1.  I think you want to shift left by `(x1 % 32)`.

Comment: You are right ... just started my IDE and trying the code. And there is a special situation currently not handled if all bits to set are within a single array item. I am fixing that now.

Comment: This looks really good.  I wonder if I can optimize out those modulus operators somehow.  Actually, I don't even know if a table look-up would be faster.

Comment: Spoke to soon.  If anything, I would be replacing the shift operators...  I wonder if that would improve performance at all.

Comment: The shift operations are really fast. I would try to get the mods and the subtraction away and may be try replacing the for loop with a while loop. But I am not sure what helps most - did not do assembler optimization for a while.

Comment: But is so simple, you could just use assembler. Sometimes I use the VC++ inline assembler and use the resulting DLL in my C# projects.

Comment: Actually, this is a Silverlight program, so I'm restricted to managed code, but it's a nice thought.  I can replace both the subtractions and shift operators with table look-ups, but I don't know if that is an improvement.  I'm not sure how to eliminate the mods.

Comment: Once again, huge thanks for the help.  This was the best response I could have hoped for.

Comment: I think the above code is not correct, in case the start and end index are both in the startIndex location!

Answer (score 2):

My solution for setting a whole range of bits in a BitArray to true or false:

```
public static BitArray SetRange(BitArray bitArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length, Boolean value)
{

    Int32[] ints = new Int32[(bitArray.Count >> 5) + 1];

    bitArray.CopyTo(ints, 0);

    var firstInt = offset >> 5;
    var lastInt = (offset + length) >> 5;

    Int32 mask = 0;

    if (value)
    {
        // set first and last int
        mask = (-1 << (offset & 31));
        if (lastInt != firstInt)
            ints[lastInt] |= ~(-1 << ((offset + length) & 31));
        else
            mask &= ~(-1 << ((offset + length) & 31));

        ints[firstInt] |= mask;

        // set all ints in between
        for (Int32 i = firstInt + 1; i < lastInt; i++)
            ints[i] = -1;
    }

    else
    {
        // set first and last int
        mask = ~(-1 << (offset & 31));
        if (lastInt != firstInt)
            ints[lastInt] &= -1 << ((offset + length) & 31);
        else
            mask |= -1 << ((offset + length) & 31);

        ints[firstInt] &= mask;

        // set all ints in between
        for (Int32 i = firstInt + 1; i < lastInt; i++)
            ints[i] = 0;

    }

    return new BitArray(ints) { Length = bitArray.Length };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
UInt32 x1 = 3;
UInt32 x2 = 9;
UInt32 newInteger = (UInt32)(Math.Pow(2, x2 + 1) - 1) & 
                   ~(UInt32)(Math.Pow(2, x1)-1);
```

Comment: I could use the left shift operator instead of Math.Pow.  ie.  ((2 << (x2+1))-1) & ~((2 << x1)-1), but I need to figure out how to do this over an array.

Comment: perhaps instead of using the shift operator, I could use a table of pre-calculated values to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to use the System.Collections.BitArray class instead of a UInt32[]?  Otherwise, I'd try something like this:

```
int minIndex = (int)x1/32;
int maxIndex = (int)x2/32;
// first handle the all zero regions and the all one region (if any)
for (int i = 0; i < minIndex; i++) {
    bitArray[i] = 0;
}
for (int i = minIndex + 1; i < maxIndex; i++) {
    bitArray[i] = UInt32.MaxValue; // set to all 1s
}
for (int i = maxIndex + 1; i < MAX_DIV_32; i++) {
    bitArray[i] = 0;
}

// now handle the tricky parts
uint maxBits = (2u << ((int)x2 - 32 * maxIndex)) - 1; // set to 1s up to max
uint minBits = ~((1u << ((int)x1 - 32 * minIndex)) - 1); // set to 1s after min

if (minIndex == maxIndex) {
    bitArray[minIndex] = maxBits & minBits;
}
else {
    bitArray[minIndex] = minBits;
    bitArray[maxIndex] = maxBits;
}
```

Comment: System.Collections.BitArray is convenient, but terribly slow.  All those range checks can really get in the way.

Comment: kvb, this looks really good.  I'm going to see if I can optimize it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored enough to try doing it with a `char` array and using `Convert.ToUInt32(string, int)` to convert to a `uint` from base 2.

```
uint Range(int l, int h)
{
  char[] buffer = new char[h];
  for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
  {
    buffer[i] = i < h - l ? '1' : '0';
  }
  return Convert.ToUInt32(new string(buffer), 2);
}
```

A simple benchmark shows that my method is about 5% faster than Angrey Jim's (even if you replace second Pow with a bit shift.)

It is probably the easiest to convert to producing a `uint` array if the upper bound is too big to fit into a single `int`. It's a little cryptic but I believe it works.

```
uint[] Range(int l, int h)
{
  char[] buffer = new char[h];
  for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
  {
    buffer[i] = i < h - l ? '1' : '0';
  }

  int bitsInUInt = sizeof(uint) * 8;
  int numNeededUInts = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)buffer.Length /
                                         (decimal)bitsInUInt);
  uint[] uints = new uint[numNeededUInts];
  for (int j = uints.Length - 1, s = buffer.Length - bitsInUInt;
       j >= 0 && s >= 0;
       j--, s -= bitsInUInt)
  {
    uints[j] = Convert.ToUInt32(new string(buffer, s, bitsInUInt), 2);
  }

  int remainder = buffer.Length % bitsInUInt;
  if (remainder > 0)
  {
    uints[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(new string(buffer, 0, remainder), 2);
  }

  return uints;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uint x1 = 3;
uint x2 = 9;

int cbToShift = x2 - x1; // 6
int nResult = ((1 << cbToShift) - 1) << x1; 

/*
  (1<<6)-1 gives you 63 = 111111, then you shift it on 3 bits left
*/
```

Comment: the range [3-9] was just a simplified example.  This needs to scale up through a range of values > 32 bits using an array.