# How to store String in to bits for reduce memory occpuied

Tags: c, string, bit-manipulation

I have one charater pointer array which points to the some stirngs

every element points to some strings
one thing in mind  strings have only 1 and 0 .

for example

i have character pointer that stores string like "100110" so its takes 6 bytes to store but i want to store this in bits so i reduce memory occpuied.

Comment: C or C++ ? They are two different languages.

Comment: The `<<` operator should help you.

Comment: Have a look into here :<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688314/converting-a-range-into-a-bit-array>

Comment: in C .. and but << help ..i am fresher in C and i have some assignment work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C style, something like this should work:

```
char* str = "100101";
unsigned out = 0;

for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
   out = (out << 1);
   if (str[i] == '1')
      out++;
}
```

(I cannot test this for now, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

**Explanation:**

```
str = "100101"
out = 0000 0000 0000 0000

i = 0:
   out = 0000 0000 0000 0000 (out << 1)
   out = 0000 0000 0000 0001 (out++ because str[0] == '1')

i = 1:
   out = 0000 0000 0000 0010 (out << 1)

[...]

i = 5:
   out = 0000 0000 0010 0100 (out << 1)
   out = 0000 0000 0010 0101 (out++ because str[5] == '1')
```

Comment: i will test. here unsigned out is char??

Comment: `unsigned` is for `unsigned int`, use the type you want, depending of your string length

Comment: can i use unsigned char out = 0;

Comment: an `unsigned char` is 1 byte (8 bits)

Comment: i want to implement huffman encoding algo after encoding i want to store my encoded value of every char in to somewhere and also reduce memory

Comment: Maybe you could make an array of `unsigned short` (16 bits), `unsigned int` or whatever, in which the ASCII code of your char is the index of its encoded value in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the STL [`bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) container? It's optimized for exactly this purpose. Alternatively, creating a `vector` of `bool` elements will internally pack bits to save space.

Comment: tell me more description about dis??

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 'strtol'? It's a standard lib function. 
Or you're writing low-level code for memory shortage hardware?

```
char *str = "010101";
int i = strtol(str ,(char**)NULL ,2);

==> i=21
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to, define that `char* []` as a global and **use its indices** for accessing it:

```
char stringLiterals [] =  { "0101010", "10010010", "111", "010100100", ... };
```

**Usage**:
 Instead of

```
char *p = stringLiteral[3];
```

use

```
unsigned int idx = 3;
```

**Rationale**: If you are compacting this string into bits for serialization purpose than it's ok. But otherwise I don't see any use case of compacting them. In my above solution, it **doesn't use any extra memory**. You already have an array of string literals; I am just asking to declare in global scope and use its index.

Also, if the string size is > 32 bytes then, you won't be able to store it in a single 32-bit `int`.

Comment: i dnt want to access i want to store "0101010" string in bits. instead of bytes

Comment: @SaurabhPatel, yes I indeed get your question. My answer suggest you the final usability within your code. You store `"010101"` somewhere and then for using it you again covert it back to `"010101"`. Instead of that, you can simply store that string literal into an array and just get its index. It's equivalent to **converting** `"010101"` into a single `int`. If you are **not** dealing with serializing your data then this technique is helpful. I assume that you want to covert the string literals and not the content of some variable, in the later case u have to use `vector` instead of array

Comment: @downvoter, please see my rational behind the answer in the comment above. If I am missing something, kindly explain.

Comment: @iammilind: "but *i want to store this in bits* so i reduce memory occpuied" (from its question). And I read you answer about 5 times to vaguely understand your point...

Comment: @Simon, and here it won't take any memory. Because he is just accessing the index of the already stored string literals. I don't find any use case of storing those literals into bits other than learning purpose (or serialization). Moreover, it is quite possible that the string length is `> 32` bytes and the OP will not be able to store it in a single 32-bit `int`. :)

Comment: @iammilind: his strings lengths are about "*maximum 15 or 16*". In your way, you have to get a global variable (which is bad in many cases), or a global constant (which is maybe not what he wants).

Comment: @iammilind dear i store my string somewhere like "110011" so its takes 6 bytes so i want to store this all value in only one byte..may be answer of Simon is helpfull to me..

Comment: @iammilind Your answer is also may be current but i have no idea about string lliterals and vector so how can i use this?

Comment: @iammilind i want to implement huffman encoding algo after encoding i want to store my encoded value of every char in to somewhere and also reduce memory

Comment: @Simon i want to implement huffman encoding algo after encoding i want to store my encoded value of every char in to somewhere and also reduce memory

Comment: Then you're not gonna compress anything if you're converting a text file into a "binary text file" (a text file filled with '0' and '1' characters).